# Send an email from a google script - trigger is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have at custom html form, sending all data into my google sheet. With this code - its working.

```
var sheetName = 'Ark1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }

 }
```

But now i want to send some data of the form to myself in an Email. For this i created an additional script like this:

```
function sendEmail(e){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 16);
 var data = dataRange.getValues();

 var row = data[0];

      var myEmail = "email@mail.com";       
      var virksomhed = row[1];
      var email = row[3];
      [...]
      var yderlig = row[15];

      var subject = "Formular: " + virksomhed;
      var message = "Yderlig:" + "\t" + yderlig; 

   MailApp.sendEmail (myEmail, email, subject, message);
   }
```

On running the script, it is working. But it is not working setting up a trigger.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong? Is it because of its a doPost function to get the data from my form? I also tried to use the MailApp.sendEmail inside the doPost function following that advise: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26659691?hl=en
But that isnt working as well - at least the way i tried to set up the code.

Here is an example of the code inside the doPost.

```
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

    var virksomhed = String(newRow[1]);
    var myEmail = 'my@email.com';
    var subject = 'Forform';
    var body = 'Indsendt formular fra' + virksomhed;
    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmail, subject, body);

  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }

 }
```

It seems like MailApp.sendEmail is just getting ignored when its inside a doPost – can that be? And if yes, is there no chance at all of getting a email notification when there is added a new row to spreadsheet?!

Comment: 1. What do you mean by `that isn't working as well`? 2. Is your script alone-standing or bound to the spreadsheet that receives the data? 3. Did you try to call `sendEmail(e)` from inside `doPost()` after releasing the lock?

Comment: 1. I do not receive an email on sendEmail(e). I ONLY receive it, when i let it run manually. But not through any trigger, or by calling it inside the doPost().
2. My script is bound to a spreadsheet, receiving data. At it does receives the data on doPost(). 
3. I also tried now to call the sendEmail(e) function after the releasing the lock, inside the doPost(). But i still do not reveice any email. It only loads the form data into the sheet.

Comment: How is your WebApp deployed (execute as, who has access)?

Comment: as "me" and anybody, even anonymous has access.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue when publishing as "the user accessing the WebApp". Because in this case the user won't have the authorization to send an email.  If you publish as "me", this should not be the case. Are you sure that the email is not sent at all (rather than landing in Spam)? Can you call `function sendEmail(e)` if you comment the `MailApp.sendEmail` line away? Did you try with `GmailApp.sendEmail()`?

Comment: Unfortunatley there is no email coming at all, i even tried an other email adress. And i do publish as "Me". How can i check if the function sendEmail(e) is called without Mail.App.sendEmail? I also tried GmailApp. --- no email is delivered as well.

Comment: If you publish as "me" and make the call to `doPost()` yourself - you should be able to see the called functions in your executions.

Comment: I can run the function sendEmail(e) manually. It works, placed under the `doPost()` function in the same script and it works also when placed in a different script. I get an email. But i dont get an email, when i fill out the form, that sends the data to the sheet. All data from from the form is placed correctly into the sheet, but i dont get an email.

Comment: Must be a permission issue. Can you try to deploy a Web App again as "me", but select a new "Project version" in the dialog? This is different from "manage versions".

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked ... After i updated "Project version" i receive now emails!

Before i also checked the authorization following this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app
And i added the "oauthScopes" to the appscript.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should publish a new version of the web app for it to use your modified code with the `doPost` callback. Inside the script editor, go to Resources, Publish Web app and publish a new version.

Comment: I did, i placed the code inside the doPost code, added a new version via "manage versions" and published new. But nothing still. Maybe its the code inside the doPost that is wrong?